# Using SED, How can I add '#' to the beginning of the last line of the file?

Tags: sed

Lets say I have this file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

How can I add '#' to the last line before "}"?

I've tried `sudo sed '91 s/}/#}/' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` 
what it did was to show me the change on screen but not actually change the file.

Comment: If your sed supports "in place" editing, use the `-i` option. Otherwise, redirect the output to a new file and rename it afterwards.

Comment: With sed `sed -i '$s/./#&/' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the file is addressed as `$`.

We can replace the beginning of the line (`^`) with `#` using the `s` command.

Putting that together, we have a very simple `sed` program:

```
$s/^/#/
```

We can execute that on your file in-place as a simple shell command:

```
sed -e '$s/^/#/' -i "$file"
```

Comment: yep it's better that way

Comment: Works!!
Thanks for the detailed info! (bookmarked until it's embedded in my head) :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, for in-place editing of a file in a script, I prefer `ed` over the non POSIX standard `sed -i` (Plus because it treats the file as a whole, and processing it a line at a time, some more complicated things are a lot easier). If you're not automating this, of course, just use `emacs` or `vi` or your favorite editor.

```
ed -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default <<EOF
$s/}/#}/
w
EOF
```